# GitHub Actions with AWS OIDC login not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, github-actions, amazon-iam

Can someone please explain me why my OIDC login from GitHub Actions to AWS is not working?

I created the OIDC Provider in the AWS console.

I have a trust-relationship in my role:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Federated": "arn:aws:iam::852523567171:oidc-provider/token.actions.githubusercontent.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "token.actions.githubusercontent.com:sub": "repo:headincloud/hic-public-dns:*",
                    "token.actions.githubusercontent.com:aud": "sts.amazonaws.com"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This should allow all branches to have access to AWS via OIDC, no?

My GitHub action is as follows:

```
name: preview-changes
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
jobs:
  up:
    name: Preview
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      id-token: write
      contents: read
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name: Configure AWS Credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v4
        with:
          role-to-assume: arn:aws:iam::852523567171:role/github-actions-dns
          aws-region: eu-west-1
```

To be clear: The listed ARN's are correct.

Still, I get this error in my Github Action:

```
Error: Could not assume role with OIDC: Not authorized to perform sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity
```

What on earth am I missing in my setup?

Answer (score 0):

Solution found, and posting here in case others ever stumble upon this.

When using `*` in condition, you need to use `StringLike` instead of `StringEquals`.